# Changing an image on hover without javascript (using asp.net-mvc3)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to make a menu with images and a title under them. On hovering either the image or the title, I want to change the title's color and the image.

This would be easy.

The problems are:

The images only have fixed height, the width varies, and the elements come from the database, so I cannot hard-code their width. I don't store the images' width and height in the database, but if there is no other solution I could do that.

I wouldn't want to load a new image on hover as I wouldn't want it to disappear if hovered the first time and the replacement image is not yet loaded. I would prefer messing with the background positions.
Also the background positions are working strangely in older IE browsers (they understand background-position-x, y not simply background-position), what is the best practice to deal with this?

The css is a static file so everything dynamic (using variables) should be inline (like the background url of the div comes from the database)

The image should be clickable just like the title. Basically the link area should be the same as the hover area (that means I would prefer to write a:hover in the css)

I would prefer not to use javascript for this (it should be possible without it)

My code is a little messy now as I have tried more than one approach and some stuff got mixed up.

```
<div class="headericons_wrap">
    @foreach (var headericon in Model) 
    {
    <div class="headericon">
        <div class="headericon_image">
            <a href="@Url.Content(headericon.LinkURL)">
                <span style="background-image:url(@Url.Content(headericon.PictureURL));"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
                @headericon.Name
        </div>
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

and the css

```
.headericons_wrap{
    float: right; max-height: 110px;
}
.headericons_wrap a img 
{
    border-style: none;

}
.headericon{
    text-align:center; 
    float:left; 
    margin:0 8px;
    max-width:96px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.headericon_image
{
    height: 80px;
    width: auto;
}

.headericon_image span
{
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: none no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}

.headericon_image a:hover span
{
    background-position: 0 100%;
}

.headericon_image a
{
    background-position: 0 0;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It does not work currently, as it does not care about the images width, just the title length, so it cuts the right side of the image, and also there is no link on the title but there should be.

A jsfiddle with 1-2 elements would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

Are your image urls variable? If not, you could simply do :hover on the headericon with a different url.

Another idea I've seen (and used) is to create one image out of two or three (two in your case), where the images are stacked on top of one another. Then, using CSS :hover, the image's x,y coordinates are changed, effectively 'shifting' the image up or down to display the other image. This 'combined' image could be created on the fly without too much headache in PHP or asp.

Comment: If you read my code, you can see that I'm using .headericon_image a:hover span
{
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
so the image is already a background-shifting div.

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically create the CSS classes to go with each header (a regular version and one with the hover selector). This could be done in the head tag portion of the file inside of style tags or you could dynamically generate the CSS file with this info (I know you don't want to, but it may make things easier).

Comment: I dont see much difference between generating css classes inline or writing an inline style="" attribute with the stuff I would write in the css class. Generating an external css is not good cache-wise as browsers tend to cache css quite aggressively.